# RelativeLayout ignores RelativeToView

Tags: xamarin.forms

Are there any rules for which views you can refer to when using RelativeToView on a RelativeLayout?

It ignores it when I use it like this...

```
RelativeLayout.YConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression ElementName=main Type=RelativeToView, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"
```

It seems to default to `RelativeToParent`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any rules for which views you can refer to when using
>   RelativeToView on a RelativeLayout?

`which views you can refer to` depending on `ElementName` you set.

In your code:

```
RelativeLayout.YConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression ElementName=main Type=RelativeToView, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"
```

The **Y** of this view is half of the height of `main`, that is 0.5 * `main.height`.

Here I give you an example:

```
    <RelativeLayout>
        <BoxView Color="Red" x:Name="redBox"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,Factor=0.15,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.8,Constant=0}" />

        <BoxView Color="Blue" x:Name="blueBox"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=redBox,Property=Height, Factor=.5, Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=redBox,Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.5,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.5,Constant=0}" />

    <BoxView Color="Orange"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=blueBox,Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=blueBox,Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=blueBox,
        Type=RelativeToView,Property=Width,Factor=.5,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=blueBox,
        Type=RelativeToView,Property=Height,Factor=.5,Constant=0}" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can see that the height of redBox is 0.8 * height(ContentView). Then I set the blueBox:

```
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=redBox,Property=Height, Factor=.5, Constant=0}"
```

So, the **Y** of `blueBox` is 0.5* 0.8 * height(ContentView).

**Note**: Both `redBox's superView` and `blueBox's superView` is ContentView.

You should calculate the right height of the View you want.

Refer: [relative-layout#usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout#usage)